Unity navmesh manages to calculate path in Editor but fails when deployed on Android device
I'm working on a game where characters are controlled using a nav mesh agent.
For month I did not have any issues with the nav mesh, but I recently have started to grow the scene and having trouble with it.
Everything works fine when I test my game in Unity, path are properly calculated and characters move around happily.
But when the build is deployed on Android, my characters get stuck. Using the debugger, I can see that pendingPath is always set to true, as if the path is never resolved.
I'm baffled. What would cause this to work on the PC and not an the Android device ? What can I do to investigate further/fix the issue ?
Thanks

does it do the same when debugged? have you put a ton of debug logs in and checked what it says?

Can you give us more information about the specifications of the phone?
Since you’ve observed that pendingPath is always true, focus on why the path isn’t resolving. Log the path points, agent positions, and any error messages related to pathfinding. Test with a simplified scene to isolate the issue.

There's nothing in the log of course as explained. It's just that I keep checking isPending and it's stays to true when run on the Android device (an old Samsung A6, ... will check on another device). I'll never debugged pathfinding before, will put some logs and see what is going on. But am not sure how to simplify the scene would solve my problem in isolating the problem. Surely if the path resolve fine when testing in the editor, it should also resolve when ran on a device no ? The only difference shoiuld be performance wise

then you need way more logging..

Update : the problem happens on a samsung S22 as well. I'm still not able to figure out why the path is not resolving on a device while it resolves without problems in the editor.

yes, i know exactly what the navmesh, (ive used both the old and the new) is, and how to use it thanks, and yes i read what you wrote, you need to add debug info so YOU can find out why..

What sort of debug info ? Be specific. There s not much to log. SetDestination is set then the path does not resolve. No exceptions are throwns. What exactly can be logged to help finding out why it does not resolve ?
